# Find a string inside another string in Matlab

Tags: string, matlab

I have to creade a function that takes two inputs: a cell array of strings (let's call it `txt`) and a single string (let's call it `str`). The function has to remove each element of the cell vector `txt` whose string is either identical to `str` or contains `str` as a substring.
For the moment I've tried with the following:

```
function c = censor( txt,str )
    c = txt;
    n = length(c);
    for i = 1:n
        a = c{ i };
        a( a == str ) = [];
        c{i} = a;
    end
end
```

But it doesn't work, it gives the error that `Matrix dimensions must agree.` I understand that it might be because `str` has more than one character, but I don't know how to find if `str` is contained in any of the strings of the cell array `txt`.

Comment: Take a look at strfind. http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html

Comment: Nice, it does what I need, but the problem is when the coincidence appears more than one time. I don't know how to remove each element once I find all the coincidences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Anders pointed out, you want to use `strfind` to look for strings inside other strings. Here is a way you could write your function. Basically apply `strfind` on the whole `txt` cell array, and then remove entries in which there was a match.

Code:

```
function censor(txt,str)
clc
clear

%// If no input are supplied..demo
if nargin ==0

    str = 'hello';
    txt = {'hellothere' 'matlab' 'helloyou' 'who are you' 'hello world'};
end

IsItThere = strfind(txt,str)
```

Now `IsItThere` is a cell array with some 1's and empty cells:

```
IsItThere = 

    [1]    []    [1]    []    [1]
```

Let's fill empty cells with 0, so we can perform logical indexing later:

```
IsItThere(cellfun('isempty',IsItThere))={0}
```

Find the indices in which a match occured:

```
IndicesToRemove = find(cell2mat(IsItThere))

IndicesToRemove =

     1     3     5
```

And remove cells:

```
txt(IndicesToRemove) = [];
```

`txt` now looks like this:

```
txt = 

    'matlab'    'who are you'

end
```

You can combine a few steps together if you like, but I hope that was clear enough :)

Here is the whole code that you can copy/paste in a .m file:

```
function censor(txt,str)
clc
clear

%// If no input are supplied..demo
if nargin ==0

    str = 'hello';
    txt = {'hellothere' 'matlab' 'helloyou' 'who are you' 'hello world'};
end

IsItThere = strfind(txt,str)

IsItThere(cellfun('isempty',IsItThere))={0}

IndicesToRemove = find(cell2mat(IsItThere))

txt(IndicesToRemove) = [];
txt
end
```

Comment: Your method works with your example but for some reason it does not work when each element of the cell array is a sentence and `str` appears more than once. Any idea on how to improve this method? It is really good but I don't know how to make it work for sentences with more than one coincidence. For example, using the first 8 lines of the US national anthem and `str = 'the'`, I get: `IsItThere = 

    [24]    [30]    [43]    [6]    [1x2 double]    [1x2 double]    [0]    [1x4 double]`

Comment: @Hec46 When there are multiple occurrences `strfind` gives the index where the `str` starts. You can use something like `IsItThere(~cellfun('isempty', IsItThere)) = {1}` before  `IsItThere(cellfun('isempty', IsItThere)) = {0}`